# How populate Spring Data Repositories with ManyToMany relationship

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

I want to populate the repository with user roles and two initial users related to those roles.

This is the JSON I want to upload:

```
[ 
    {
        "_class": "models.Role",
        "@id": 1,
        "name": "ROLE_BLOG_ADMIN",
        "description": "Rol de los administradores del blog"
    },
    {
        "_class": "models.Role",
        "@id": 2,
        "name": "ROLE_BLOG_CONTRIBUTOR",
        "description": "Rol de los editores de artículos"
    },
    { 
        "_class": "models.User",
        "username": "sergio11",
        "password": "$2a$10$0eCQpFRdw8i6jJzjj/IuNuKpJYnLaO5Yp9xSJ3itcfPmQNXVhmNyu",
        "email": "gfhdsgfjhdsgfjhdsgf@gmail.com",
        "fullName": "Sergio Sánchez Sánchez",
        "roles": [1, 2]
    },
    {
        "_class": "models.User",
        "username": "dani33",
        "password": "$2a$10$0eCQpFRdw8i6jJzjj/IuNuKpJYnLaO5Yp9xSJ3itcfPmQNXVhmNyu",
        "email": "danihiglesias@usal.es",
        "fullName": "Daniel de la Iglesia",
        "roles": [2]
    }
]
```

I am using `JsonIdentityInfo` in the Roles entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=IntSequenceGenerator.class, property="@id")
public class Role implements Serializable
```

I have included `Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean` in the context:

```
@Bean(name="repositoryPopulator")
    public Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean  provideJackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean(){
        Resource sourceData = new ClassPathResource("data.json");
        Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean factory = new Jackson2RepositoryPopulatorFactoryBean();
        factory.setResources(new Resource[] { sourceData });
        return factory;
    }
```

But, no role is associated with any user.

This is the association:

```
@ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
      name="USER_ROLES",
      joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
      inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Role> roles;
```

Does anyone know how to fix them?

Comment: Does this solve your problem: http://www.sureshpw.com/2014/05/importing-json-with-references-into.html ?

Comment: thanks for answering @JensSchauder, but it does not work when it's an array. I get an error saying "no repository has been found for the java.util.ArrayList domain model"

Comment: can you post the code for your CustomJackson2ResourceReader and DataExtractor?

Comment: I have tried it exactly as in tutorial changing the JSON above as the tutorial. 
The only difference is that in the tutorial it is associated with a single value ("owener": 1) and I am linking it with several ("roles": [1, 2])

Comment: I think it is not necessary to put the code because it is exactly the same

Comment: Ah, I see. I thought the dataExtractor would "manually" resolve the ids and therefore need some  adaption.

Comment: I have tried changing "roles": [1, 2] by "roles": [  { "@ref": 1 },  { "@ref": 2} ]. But this exception occurs when doing the USER_ROLES insert the first time: org.hibernate.TransientObjectException: object references an unsaved transient instance - save the transient instance beforeQuery flushing: models.Role;

Answer (score 2):

It should only complain about a missing constructor for the Role entity, for me everything went smoothly with the following :

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class Role implements Serializable {

    public Role() {
    }

    public Role(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Id
    @JsonProperty("@id")
    private Integer id;

   //additional properties, getters & setters
   ...  
}

@Entity
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private Integer id;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @JoinTable(
            name="USER_ROLES",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="USER_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="ROLE_ID", referencedColumnName="ID"))
    private Set<Role> roles;

    //additional properties, getters & setters
    ...
}
```

And I properly get :

```
[  
   {  
      "id":1,
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "name":"ROLE_BLOG_ADMIN",
            "@id":1
         },
         {  
            "name":"ROLE_BLOG_CONTRIBUTOR",
            "@id":2
         }
      ],
      "email":"sss4esob@gmail.com"
   },
   {  
      "id":2,
      "roles":[  
         {  
            "name":"ROLE_BLOG_CONTRIBUTOR",
            "@id":2
         }
      ],
      "email":"danihiglesias@usal.es"
   }
]
```

Can you provide more of your entities code if this isn't working for you ? Do you encounter any exception ?

Comment: It works. I've tried *so* many different setups, none as simple and clean as this, and none of them worked. Thanks!